# Need help understanding wrong output from Perl regex string substitution

Tags: regex, perl

I was hoping someone would know why I am getting unexpected output from my Perl code using regex.  I am automating the process of converting code syntax manually (see below).

Original syntax:

```
var_name1.insert((uint8_t) data_buffer1, parameter1, parameter2);
var_name2.insertFromRight((uint32_t) data_buffer2, parameter1, parameter2);
var_name3.insert( data_buffer3, parameter1, parameter2); // comment 
var_name4.insertFromRight(data_buffer4, parameter1, parameter2);
```

New syntax:

```
var_name.insert<parameter1, parameter2>(data_buffer)
var_name.insertFromRight<parameter1, parameter2>(data_buffer)
```

Snippet of Perl code of interest:

```
while($curr_line = <INFILE>) {
    chomp($curr_line);
      ...
        my $params = $curr_line;
        $params =~ s/.*\..*?\(//g; #strip variable name & method name
        $params =~ s/\);.*//g;  #strip ending brace and comma
        my $data_buffer = $params;
        $data_buffer =~ s/,.*//g; #Erase everything after first comma
        $params =~ s/$data_buffer,//g;

        $curr_line =~ s/\(.*\);/<$params>($data_buffer);/g; #new syntax
         ...

        # Sends output to a new output file
        print OUTFILE "$curr_line\n";
}
```

My code works and converts to the new syntax for the third and for examples that don't include a casted data_buffer variable.  But for the casted examples, I get following odd output ($ = means 8, 16, 32, or 64)

```
var_name.insert< (uint$_t) data_buffer, parameter1, parameter2>((uint$_t)data_buffer)
var_name.insertFromRight<(uint$_t) data_buffer,parameter1, parameter2>((uint$_t) data_buffer)
```

This part of my code $params =~ s/$data_buffer,//g;
is not stripping away the data_buffer name from the parameters list for these casted values for some reason. Any hint on where I may be misunderstanding what I am doing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that the `()` used for the cast are significant in regex syntax. `*` for pointer-casts would be too.

You need to quote/escape `$data_buffer` when inside a regex match to have it match literally.

```
$params =~ /\Q$data_buffer\E,//;
```

(And you don't need all those `/g` parameters, you're only expecting one substitution.)

Assuming your input is as regular as show, I just wouldn't use regex for this. Substrings and splitting are quite sufficient and less complex to deal with here. For example:

```
foreach my $line (<>) {
  my $param_start = index($line, '(');
  my $param_end  = rindex($line, ')');
  my $all_args = substr($line, $param_start+1, $param_end-$param_start-1);
  my @args = (split(',', $all_args));
  printf "%s<%s,%s>(%s)%s"
    , substr($line, 0, $param_start-1)
    , $args[1]
    , $args[2]
    , $args[0]
    , substr($line, $param_end+1)
    ;
}
```

And if your input is much less regular, using a real (C++?) parser will become necessary.

Comment: thanks for your input.  I suspected it might be have been this issue but when I attempted to use double or single quotes (including comma) it didn't work for me then.  At work we use Perl for scripting so I'm doing this pretty manually but I'll look into C++ parsers.  The code I am converting is C compiled code using a C++ API (so, mixed in a way) into a new C++ API.  As you can tell my Perl coding is pretty hacked since I'm new at it but I'll take your advice into consideration for future .